# Google Tag manager code added with the help of DTM is not working

Tags: google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I had a request to add Google tag manager to our website and i added it using Dynamic Tag Manage (DTM). I created a page load rule and added this script. But my client is saying it is not working as DTM adds the code to the page with an Iframe. Is there a way we can fix this issue?

Alternative is directly add in the page. I don't want to go in that route as we have to update our page templates for these tags.

Comment: are you adding it as a 3rd party tag as non-sequential html?

Comment: Yes i have added it as 3rd party tag non-sequential html.

Comment: In DTM non-sequential html containers are added in iframes. You need to change it to sequential.  But actually, even then it's probably going to cause some problems with GTM.  You should not output tag manager code through other tag managers.  They rely on being put directly on the page according to their instructions because how you put something on a page affects how it can in turn put things onto a page

Comment: Page load rules -> Custom Javascript -> Sequential Javascript and tick checkbox Execute globally.

Comment: Google tag manger code instructions says that we need to add the script immediately after the body tag. It works only if we add it that way. But i don't think we have that option with Dynamic Tag manager. I guess i have to go back and change our page template to do this update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid adding Tag Manager code in any other tag containers. It is built to be a standalone tag management solution and Google won't provide support if it's embedded in a 3rd party solution.

Your best option is to just select one tag management solution and stick with that. Having multiple tag managers kind of defeats the purpose, no?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use one TMS to deploy the code of another TMS.  None of them were designed to be deployed in that manner and all sorts of bad / odd things could happen.